# Suggestions regarding Hadamard Matrices

Tags: matrices, research, hadamard-matrices

I am a grade 12 student, and for this semester, I am interested in doing a math research paper instead of a science one. I've looked up the internet regarding the different topics I can tackle on, but I'm still unsure of which topic to finalize with, because most of them are only taught in college. So far, I have been reading about Hadamard Matrices and their applications and it interests me, because I'm a big fan of algebra. But there is still that sense of doubt in me if I don't get anything. Any suggestions regarding about what can be researched about Hadamard Matrices will be useful, other topics may also do. Thank you.

Comment: I guess that [Hadamard matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) are already well investigated, so it should be hard to obtain new results in this topic. As alternative research topics I saw somewhere in Internet  open problems for undergraduates, but if you like matrices I can suggest you to try to attack [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209440/selecting-columns-of-a-set-of-boolean-matrices-with-constraint-on-the-ones-in-ea/209671#comment519613_209671) question.